# Migrate DB error, Unable to process payload

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Recently I have switched on Macbook from Windows, and I had to re-do all my working processes.

I am working to set up a WordPress local website to look like the live one, and usually how I would have done that is through Git and then MigrateDB (pull) from the live.

I came across this error while pulling, at the Media stage:

> Unable to process payload.

[image: The Error in question]

I was wondering if anyone has ever been through this and you might be able to help.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good method if you get such vague error messages. Why not simply export the database, copy it to the new system, and import it? See: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/#more-184 or use PhpMyAdmin: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question as I found out why this was happening and leave it here with the hopes that if anyone ever encounters this issue, will know what to do.

The "Unable to process payload." happens due to Xampp, if you want to download the latest version on a Macbook M1 type processor, won't work, and you are forced to download an older version 7.2.3, this version does not work well with some of the WordPress Plugins so you will get all bunch of errors.

**Solution**
Get rid of XAMPP, if you are using a Macbook M1 type processor and install MAMPP, the free version, it will work fine and smoothly.